# How can I generate a video file directly from an FFmpeg filter with no actual input file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

FFmpeg has a number of video generating filters, listed in the documentation as "[video sources](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Sources)":

- cellauto
- color
- mptestsrc
- fei0r_src
- life
- nullsrc, rgbtestsrc, testsrc

Those are great for using with other filters like overlay, but is there any way that I can generate a movie consisting of just one of those video sources without any input video?

Something like:

```
ffmpeg -vf color=red" red_movie.mp4
```

Except that that errors out with **`At least one input file must be specified`**.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It looks like the options have changed slightly in recent versions.

To use the filter input sources, you have to:

1. Set the input format to the libavfilter virtual device using: `-f lavfi`
2. Set the filter input source using the `-i` flag (not `-vf`)
3. Provide arguments as **complete key-value pairs**, like: `color=color=red`

This works for `ffplay`, too, to test your filtergraph:  `ffplay -f lavfi -i color`

## Examples

In these examples I've added `-t 30` to specify that I only want 30 seconds of output.

### Color (Red)

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=red -t 30 red.mp4
                     ^     ^    ^
                     |     |    |
                   filter key value
```

The key can be shortened to its abbreviated form: `-i color=c=red`

### SMPTE Color Bars Pattern

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i smptebars -t 30 smpte.mp4
```

### Test Source Pattern

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p testsrc.mp4
```

[image]

In order for this to playback reliably, you might need to set the pixel format with: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

By default, ffmpeg will use yuv444p (x264, High 4:4:4 Predictive), which [some players aren't yet able to decode](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-June/015690.html).

For instance, the video it creates is crashing VLC 2.0.7 and is just 30 seconds of black in QuickTime Player 10.2 (Mac OS X 10.8.4).

More info on test source [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide#TestSource).

### RGB Test Source

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i rgbtestsrc -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 rgbtestsrc.mp4
```

As with the last example, this might not work for you unless you set the pixel format to yuv420p as shown.

For posterity, here's the version I'm using:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.1
libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
```

Comment: For those what to specify the video resolution:
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1280x720 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p testsrc.mp4` is for you.

Comment: When you need a video with the color and specified size: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=c=black:size=1280x720" -t 30 black30sec1280x720.mp4`

Answer (score 24):

Though hinted at in the documentation, this isn't explicitly spelled out.  I was pleased to figure it out, so I thought I'd share.

The key is to use the special format [`lavfi`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi):

> Libavfilter input virtual device.
>
> This input device reads data from the open output pads of a libavfilter filtergraph.
>
> For each filtergraph open output, the input device will create a corresponding stream which is mapped to the generated output. Currently only video data is supported. The filtergraph is specified through the option ‘graph’.

Essentially, `lavfi` format causes the input to be treated as a video filter instead of a filename.

Thus, to make a movie consisting of nothing but red, the command is:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=red -frames:v 200 red_movie.mp4
```

(Specifying the number of frames or otherwise limiting the input is *crucial* as filters generally have no fixed "end" point, and will happily go on generating video forever.)

Comment: You can in fact use a complete filtergraph as an `-i` input when using `-f lavfi`. Here's a filterchain example: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i life,edgedetect,negate,fade=in:0:100 -frames:v 200 life.mp4`