# Making a green screen background in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a green screen background that I can use to overlay other stuff on top of. I'm using information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18141519/3333) and using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=green -s 1920x1080 -t 3600 -r 60 small_green.mp4
```

However, when I open it up in Quicktime, the inspector window seems to be saying that it's actually 1440x1080 instead of 1920x1080.

[image]

And when I bring it into VLC, it seems to be saying that it's 1920x1090
[image]

But `ffprobe` seems to be saying it's 1920x1080:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'small_green.mp4':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100   Duration: 01:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], 34 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

And when I bring it into `Garmin VIRB Edit`, it reports that it's 1440x1080. So how do I make `ffmpeg` spit out a video that really is HD 1920x1080 resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFmpeg source filters have a default size they output to, if not specified. It's 320x240 in the case of the color filter. Your scale argument resizes the color filter's output to 1920x1080 but ffmpeg thinks that you wish to preserve the source aspect ratio, in this case, 4:3, so that's the display aspect ratio it writes into the file. A 1920x1080 video with a 4:3 ratio is effectively 1440x1080, which is what QT reports.

You need to set the size directly within color (or set the correct aspect ratio afterwards).

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=color=green:s=1920x1080 -t 3600 -r 60 small_green.mp4
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing it that way versus `-s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9`?

Comment: `-s` inserts a scaler after the color is generated, whereas the size specified within color sets the output size of the color filter, i.e. the former is like printing a 4'x6' photo, then blowing it up to 8'x12', the latter is executing the original print at 8'x12'. In this particular case, for a uniform solid color visual, quality isn't affected, but the scaler inherits the aspect ratio (4:3) generated by the filter which leads to undesired result. The aspect switch sets the aspect flag in the container, not the video stream. Some players respect it, some don't.