# can't read mp4 in opencv3.2 (ubuntu, python3)

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg, cmake

I've ran into a problem with my opencv installation, it is unable to open an mp4 video. My system is ubuntu 16.04, 64bit, opencv3.2 used from python 3.5.

`VideoCapture.read` returns `False` and `None`.

There are other questions with this problem, but they target different platforms or different opencv versions.

Apparently, I'm missing the proper codec.
So I ran `make uninstall` from my build directory, purged `opencv*` with apt and built from source again. This time making sure that `ffmpeg` was installed before the compilation.

Here are my steps:

- clone opencv and opencv_contrib
- `cd opencv/`
- `mkdir build`
- `cd build`
- `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..`
- `make -j 8`
- `sudo make install`

I checked the output of cmake, ffmpeg is there:

```
Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.60.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 56.40.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 54.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
```

But the problem persists. How can I fix this ?

**UPDATE**

I had to manually remove some .so files from /usr/local.

Then I installed all avi related codecs I could find.
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Codecs/
plus libavcodec-extra and ffmpeg

Then I recompiled and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp4 videos usually contain videos encoded with h264. This is one of the codecs that are patented and some may require a license, which is why they cannot be shipped by default in ubuntu. You need to install `libavcodec-extra` in order to enable support for h264 in ffmpeg.

Comment: I removed opencv (sudo make uninstall), then installed libavcodec-extra, then compiled again. The problem is unchanged

Comment: There are many moving parts here!
Hm. Can you verify this is actually ffmpeg, and not python choosing the wrong opencv version by creating a test video?
[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640458/how-can-i-generate-a-video-file-directly-from-an-ffmpeg-filter-with-no-actual-in) shows how to generate a video file from test data generators inside. Verify you are using the version of ffmpeg you want to by executing `which ffmpeg` on the command line.

Comment: You're definitely right about the moving parts. This time I not only ran make uninstall but also manually searched for .so files and python packages. To make sure that no configuration or old import path was left. Then I installed all avi related plugins I could find, until cmake would pickup a version for all the plugins listed in the media i/o. Including libavcodec-extra and many gstreamer plugins, etc. Now it works. Your answer about installing the correct codecs is definitely the right direction. I can't 100% say that it was libavcodec-extra, but you still solved the problem for me. Thanks